# Why does R find a data.frame variable that isn't in the data.frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

Why does this not cause an error ?

```
> str(u)
'data.frame':   8879 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ bundle_qty: int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ mail_a    : num  1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 ...

> head(u$mail)
[1] 1 1 1 1 0 0
```

Variable `mail` isn't in data.frame `u` !!! Shouldn't `u$mail` return `NULL` ??

Even when I start from scratch with dummy data:

```
> rm(list=ls())
> u <- data.frame( bundle_qty = c(1,1,1,1), mail_a = c(1,1,1,1))
> str(u)
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ bundle_qty: num  1 1 1 1
 $ mail_a    : num  1 1 1 1
> u <- data.frame( bundle_qty = c(1L,1L,1L,1L), mail_a = c(1,1,1,1))
> str(u)
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ bundle_qty: int  1 1 1 1
 $ mail_a    : num  1 1 1 1
> u$mail
[1] 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: @thelatemail that should be an answer. Remember to include fortune(312)

Comment: That was fast. Didn't know about the partial matching. Sounds like a dangerous thing not to know: thanks a lot. How do I select your answer?

Comment: @user2105469 - I have translated it to an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Partial matching, which the `$` operator uses, will return a value if it can uniquely identify a variable given the stem (e.g. - `mail`) you provide.

E.g. - there is nothing else starting with `mail` in your `data.frame`, so you get `mail_a` returned.

`u["mail"]` will throw an error though.

To give a further example showing where it works as you thought it would:

```
test <- data.frame(aa=1:10,aaa=letters[1:10])

> test$aa
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
> test$aaa
 [1] a b c d e f g h i j
Levels: a b c d e f g h i j
> test$a
NULL
```

And `fortune(312)` that @mnel refers to is:

> "The problem here is that the $ notation is a magical shortcut and like
> any other magic if used incorrectly is likely to do the programmatic
> equivalent of turning yourself into a toad."
>
> - Greg Snow (in response to a user that wanted to access a column whose
>   name is stored in y via x$y rather than x[[y]])
>   R-help (February 2012)

---

Some relevant sections of [R Language Definition](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-lang.html):

[3.4.1 Indexing by vectors](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-lang.html#Indexing-by-vectors)

...assume that the expression is `x[i]`. Then the following possibilities exist according to the type of `i`

**Character**. The strings in `i` are matched against the names attribute of `x` and the resulting integers are used. For `[[` and `$` partial matching is used if exact matching fails, so `x$aa` will match `x$aabb` if `x` does not contain a component named `"aa"` and `"aabb"` is the only name which has prefix `"aa"`. For `[[`, partial matching can be controlled via the `exact` argument which defaults to `NA` indicating that partial matching is allowed, but should result in a warning when it occurs. Setting `exact` to `TRUE` prevents partial matching from occurring, a `FALSE` value allows it and does not issue any warnings. Note that `[` always requires an exact match. The string `""` is treated specially: it indicates ‘no name’ and matches no element (not even those without a name). Note that partial matching is only used when extracting and not when replacing.

[see also `?Extract`]

[4.3.2 Argument matching](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-lang.html#Argument-matching)

The first thing that occurs in a function evaluation is the matching of formal to the actual or supplied arguments. This is done by a three-pass process:

1. **Exact matching on tags**. For each named supplied argument the list of formal arguments is searched for an item whose name matches exactly. It is an error to have the same formal argument match several actuals or vice versa.
2. **Partial matching on tags**. Each remaining named supplied argument is compared to the remaining formal arguments using partial matching. If the name of the supplied argument matches exactly with the first part of a formal argument then the two arguments are considered to be matched. It is an error to have multiple partial matches. Notice that if `f <- function(fumble, fooey) fbody`, then `f(f = 1, fo = 2)` is illegal, even though the 2nd actual argument only matches `fooey`. `f(f = 1, fooey = 2)` is legal though since the second argument matches exactly and is removed from consideration for partial matching. If the formal arguments contain `...` then partial matching is only applied to arguments that precede it.
3. **Positional matching**.

---

Note that when [subsetting a `tibble`](https://tibble.tidyverse.org/reference/subsetting.html)

> Partial matching of column names with `$` and `[[` is not supported, and `NULL` is returned. For `$`, a warning is given.

Comment: It might be good to mention `u[['mail']]`, and `u[['mail', exact = FALSE`]]` (the latter being `u$mail` calls)

Comment: (-1) Not enough pictures of cats

Comment: @mnel - write that as an additional answer and I can offer you a shiny +1 (no cat picture though, sorry).

Answer (score 9):

```
u$mail
```

Is calling the equivalent of

```
u[['mail', exact = FALSE]]
```

It will use partial matching to find a named element (column)

```
u[['mail']]
```

Will not use partial matching and thus won't find any column.

It is safer to use `[[`  as noted in fortune(312)

```
 /\_/\
( o o )
== Y ==
 - -
```

Comment: ASCII art is hard on a mobile!